# how to change background color and Box size of jQuery graphical radio buttons?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this JQuery for graphical Radio Button Sets but want to know how could i change the background colors of the buttons?

1. I would like to know how to change all thee backgrounds  ( Standard, hover, checked )
2. I would like to know how to change the box sizes of the button sets.

Can anyone tell me?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">   
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Button - Radios</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#radio").buttonset();
      }); 
    </script>
  </head>   
  <body>  
    <form>
      <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio">
        <label for="radio1"><img src="image1.gif" /></label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked">
        <label for="radio2"><img src="image2.gif" /></label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio">
        <label for="radio3"><img src="image3.gif" /></label>
      </div>
    </form>  
  </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your CSS too. Try to always create a working fiddle.

Comment: background color is coming from image which is on ".ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default" class in jquery.css file

Comment: can you tell me a code line how to change ? i am totaly new with this...

Comment: in your CSS file put .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {background: url('your image url'); !important }

Comment: @florianmaier try and let me know if not able to do I'll provide you demo for this.

Answer (score 0):

DOM explorer in F12 tools of the browser is your friend.
If you're using the standard jQueryUI, the inputs are generated to a `buttonset` by making new controls to take their places. The background color of the `buttonset` is actually a background of a new `label`, whose css comes from `jquery-ui.css` (or `jquery-ui.min.css`), and classes applied, affecting background-color, are normally

- .ui-state-default
- .ui-widget-content
- .ui-widget-header

By selecting the control in the DOM-explorer, you can see which classes are applied, and from what .css-file they come from. Also works when hovered or selected. Just open the .css, ctrl+f to find the correct classes and change the value.
Go seek and tweak.